# Send mail works locally but not on server?

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, sendmail, ports

This code works locally, but when I upload it to my server on Godaddy, it does not send the e-mail. Any idea why it doesn't work on their server? What do I need to change?

```
try {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

    mail.From = new MailAddress("Myemail@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("Myemail@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "New sign up";
    mail.Body = "New member";

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Myemail@gmail.com", "**Mypass**");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Are you catching an exception?

Answer (score 2):

They may be blocking outgoing SMTP connections in order to prevent spammers from using their service to send spam.  You should check what error messages you're getting and check your server host's policy.

Comment: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.53.109:25 ------- that is the error i got.

Comment: Looks like they ARE blocking port 25 then :-(

Comment: Godaddy have blocked port 25 for some time now.  http://www.stemkoski.com/godaddy-dedicated-server-hosting-blocks-port-25/

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to do when sending from inside a site hosted from Godaddy. Use their relay server to send the message (this won't work from your dev machine, you'll have to test it live after you upload it). [Here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/955/what-email-or-relay-server-should-i-use-in-my-aspnet-35-code) is the relay server info. Also make sure the "from" address is an email within the same domain. I usually use the same as the toAddress. See [here](http://www.cosmocentral.com/2009/01/553-sorry-your-mail-was-administratively-denied/) for info on why this is necessary.

This is the code I'm using to send from a site inside Godaddy:

```
        btnSend.Disabled = true;

        const string serverHost = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
        var msg = new MailMessage(toAddress, toAddress);
        msg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(emailFrom);

        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = emailBody;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

        try
        {
            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = serverHost;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("account", "password");
            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log the errors so that we can see them somewhere
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your email via the godaddy smtp servers. I experienced the same issue with them before I think. I believe they give instructions of how to login via their FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to the server, try to telnet smtp.google.com via 25 and 465 ports also. If you get a timeout, then you're likely firewalled from connecting to these ports outside a certain IP range.
Port 587 is for TLS. As you're using SSL, try port 465.